# Access inner class private variable in outer class

Tags: c++

```
//In file1.hpp
class A
{
    protected:      
    class B
    {
        public:
        B () {};
    };
};

// In file2.hpp

class C
{
    public:
    void getValue()
    { 
      D obj; ---- error: no matching function for call to D
      printf("%d\n",obj.c);  
    }
    class D : public A::B 
    {
        friend class C; -- I tried writing this but still no luck.
        public:
        D(int a, int b) : c(a), d(b) {}
        virtual ~D() {}
        //something
        private:
        int c; int d;
    };

    class E : public D
    {
        E() : D(1,2) {}
        virtual ~E() {}
    };
}

int main()
{
    C::E obj;
}
```

In the public function, getValue I want to access the private member variables of the class D which are (c and d). How can I do that? I tried putting "friend class C" inside class D and then tried creating an object of class D inside getValue function but instead of getting a value like c=5 or d=6, I always get 0.

If I print the value in the following area, I get the correct value. I won't be able to show you how getValue is called but just imagine that it is called somehow. I just need to print c,d in that.

```
    D(int a, int b)
    : c(a), d(b) {};
```

EDIT: At the time of instantiation in getValue, I do something like this
D obj; ---  error: no matching function for call to D

Comment: Using `friend` works just fine: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qn4x1M33z There must be something unrelated broken in your test.

Comment: @Frank warning: 'obj' is used uninitialized in this function. I get this warning and when I try to print it, it always gives 0

Comment: you need to show us code that produces your error. We can't do much otherwise, especially since the breakage clearly is happening in the parts you haven't shared.

Comment: @Frank I just edited the question. As shown in the code, I want to print values 1,2 in getValue function. I am instantiating class E which should pick up values 1,2. In class D, in constructor of class D, if I print 1,2 it gets printed ok. But when I try to print them in getValue it gives me 0

Comment: I edited it again to show where I am trying to print it and what error it is giving me

Comment: `D obj;` The `D` class doesn't have a default constructor. you want to do `D obj(1, 2);` Your problem is the same as the following program: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xozdvc8T5

Comment: @Frank but the values 1,2 are in class E. I want to instantiate class E, get the values from there (1,2) , go to class D and then eventually go to getValue function where I want to print those 1,2. That's the whole point. I printed private variables (c,d) and they are coming correct in class D. but I want to access those variables now in class C with the updated value. if this way does not work, could you suggest some other method of doing? My whole purpose is to instantiate class E, get the hardcoded values present in class E and then print them in getValue function

Comment: Oh, I get what you are trying to do. I think you are very confused about the relationship between classes and inner classes. Objects to type `C` do not contain an instance of type `D` or `E`. So get_value() as a member of C is nonsensical. That method belongs on class D directly.

Comment: @Frank My method is in class C only. So how do I restructure this keeping the classes as it is. I can instantiate class E, get the values from there (1,2) and eventually I want to use those values in getValue function. Thats my whole point. what can I do differently to make it work?
I HAVE to instantiate class E only. 
I HAVE to use the values in class E only.
I CANNOT change the place of getValue function

Comment: `get_value()` is a non-static method of `C`. It can only ever be called on an instance of `C`. If the only class you are allowed to instantiate is `E` and `E` does not inherit from `C`, then it's just impossible to call `get_value()`. End of story.

Comment: From those "have to"s and "cannot"s, I gather that there is a lot of context around this that you haven't mentioned, and I suspect a misunderstanding somewhere.

Comment: @Frank The answer which is mentioned in the post works ok for me and that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let take the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

//In file1.hpp
class A
{
protected:      
    class B
    {
    public:
        B () = default;
    };
    friend class C; // <-- bad idea
};

// In file2.hpp

class C
{
public:
    void getValue()
    {
        // Creating an object E?
        E objE;
        // Access c and d
        std::cout << "c:" << objE.c << ", d:" << objE.d << std::endl;
    }
    
    class D : public A::B // <-- bad idea?
    {
    public:
        D(int a, int b): c(a), d(b) {}
        virtual ~D() {}
        //something
    private:
        int c; // dangerous to not initialize basic types
        int d;
        friend class C; // <-- bad idea
    };

    class E : public D
    {
    public:
        E() : D(1,2) {}
        virtual ~E() {}
    };
};

int main()
{
    C objC;
    objC.getValue();
}
```

( you can run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/hNfm7Pvg0f )

First is, to have an instance of E to access in `C::getValue`, so I instantiated an object.

`private` and `protected` indicate that those properties and methods are not available publicly (encapsulation) and that is exactly what you are trying to do. You can make exceptions with `friend` keyword, but that is rarely a good idea (I probably use it twice in my 20 years carrier). But hey! it works.

Comment: But I want to print values 1,2. I do not want to print 42,7.
Also I have to instantiate class E not class C.
My point is to instantiate class E take those values from there (1,2) and then print them in getValue

Comment: 1, 2 comes from the constructor of `E`. so you need an instance of `E`, not `C`. Let check this modification (modified answer)

Comment: I am sorry but did you modify the answer? I am still seeing the instantiation of C class in main.cpp

Comment: I see your link now, it is coming 1,2 which I want. But do i have to write 42,7 (or any random value) over there?

Comment: It was a left over. sorry

Comment: As a suggestion, you can avoid class `A` at all, `namespace A` can be an alternative. Also, with `D::get_c()` and `D::get_d()` you can avoid the second friend case. https://onlinegdb.com/uo5i5-22l

Comment: Yes that was a great idea. Now I don't have to use "friend class" anymore.